# Добавить все файлы из директории в output Webpack'a

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

У меня в корне проекта есть директория, где хранятся json файлы. Вопрос: как при запуске webpack сделать, чтобы все json файлы из определенной папки добавились в вывод и были сохранены под своими именами в output директории?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить вопрос с помощью **[CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/)**.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать loader для этих файлов. { test: /.json$/, type: 'json' } для json файлов в webpack 5